# lua: why the character "$" cause "unexpected symbol near $"

Tags: lua, special-characters

I am newbie in Lua. I write a script in which there is a line

```
ISH_activation.getState() = CONST_ACTIVATION_STATE$ON
```

Then, I need to write another C++ script to read this line from Lua and parse it. Now the problem is that, when I try to debug the lua script itself, at this line it gives me the error "unexpected symbol near '$'".

I don't know why this would happen. Is format like "CONST_ACTIVATION_STATE$ON" not allowed in Lua? And is "$" a special character in Lua that we cannot use it?(But I didn't find anything mentioning this)....

Comment: Even after enclosing RHS in quotes, the LHS in your assignment is not an L-value in Lua.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for your comments! You mean this command cannot be read and parsed by C++ ?

Comment: This line isn't a correct Lua statement, it will cause syntax error.  But you can store arbitrary text inside Lua script within Lua comment `--[[ ... ]]`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff hmmm...thanks a lot...I need to figure out how to modify the lua script...

Comment: Do you need this line to be executed?  Do you want to get `CONST_ACTIVATION_STATE` value by executing Lua script?

Comment: actually I just wanna my C++ script to read lua and parse this. I make it in this way because I am using lua to rewrite another script which was written in xml-simkin and we need the same function. This command was in original script and the whole workflow is that the C++ script can read from the original script and parse it, so I am thinking doing the same thing for lua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, did you find anything saying that you *can* use `$`? :)

Yes, you cannot use dollar signs in identifiers. From the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1):

> Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of letters, digits, and underscores, not beginning with a digit. Identifiers are used to name variables, table fields, and labels.

If you really want to keep the dollar sign you could use strings instead

```
"CONST_ACTIVATION_STATE$ON"
```

Comment: oh thanks..I found nothing talking about the usage of this dollar sign...I will try this without dollar sign..Any special characters (e.g. $.@,#,£...) cannot be used in Lua identifiers?

Comment: You can only use letters, digits and underscores. See my edit.